# Computing Output Pixel-wise Gradient Norm in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd, autodiff

I am looking for an efficient way of computing \hat{x} of dimensions (b x c x h x w) defined per sample as:

[image: eq]

where x is the output of the same dimensions generated by a model with parameters \theta, and

i,j: index the height and width of the 2D output feature map

k: indexes the channel dimension

l: indexes the parameters.

How do I accomplish this with x.backward()? Is there an efficient way of doing this?

If I did x.backward(torch.ones_like(x)), I would compute the sum of the gradients in the above equation in the place of sum of their absolute values.

Brute-force way to do this would be to loop over each pixel in the output map and compute .backward(). But, that would be incredibly expensive. Is there an efficient way which avoids the loop?

Answer (score 0):

After you call `.backward()` on your loss, PyTorch calculates all the gradients for you each of which has a [`.norm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.norm) function. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

For example:

```
x = torch.rand((4,3,3), requires_grad=True)   # Some output volume
y = torch.rand((4,3,3), requires_grad=True)   # Some output volume
z = x + y
loss = z.sum()
loss.backward() 

print(x.grad)          # Print gradients for x
print(x.grad.norm(1))  # Print the L1 norm for these gradients
```